# Resource temporarily unavailable rtmps facebook

Tags: raspbian

I want to use rtmps protocol, but it doesn't works.

I get this error:

```
 [rtmps @ 0x19a4a50] Cannot open connection tls://live-api-s.facebook.com:443
 rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/6462222?s_bl=1: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Can you say why?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks more like a Facebook problem or a problem with the connection between you and FB, and not a Raspbian / Raspberry Pi problem.  Has this only happened once?  If not, how long did you wait between tries?  What software are you using?  (Please edit this info into your question rather than replying as a comment.)

Comment: I think the problem comes from gnuTLS.